# Can NRI invest in a unlisted company in US

Tags: india, investing

I have NRE and NRO account in Axis Bank, can I invest in a new company (unlisted) in USA, by transfering money from NRE / NRO account ?

Thank in advance

Regards,
Prasad

Answer (score 1):

INR held in an NRE account can be converted to non-Indian currencies without any problems. Converting money in an NRO account is more difficult but do-able. Whether it is wise for you to invest in a privately held company is a different issue.